# GitHub Pages site cannot find files (404 errors)

Tags: github

On my GitHub pages site I get the following error:

[image: 404 errors]

I have also had the same problem on another repository.

I have run `install` with `npm`, `bower`, and `gulp` already to check all dependencies are installed.

So I wrote To GitHub support and they told me "It looks like your `index.html` file is trying to load files that don't exist".

I created this all with the yeoman generator; I didn't make any changes .

If someone has any idea about this please tell me.

Comment: https://github.com/neiromendez/test-reusable,  this is my repository

Answer (score 3):

The 404 errors are correct, those [paths do not exist](https://github.com/neiromendez/test-reusable/tree/gh-pages/) on your `gh-pages` branch as [they are required to be](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/) for this to work.

```
| Type of GitHub  Pages Site           | Pages default domain &  host location on GitHub | Publishing Branch |
|--------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------|-------------------|
| User Pages Site                      | username.github.io                              | master            |
| Organization Pages Site              | orgname.github.io                               | master            |
| Project Page Owned By a User Account | username.github.io/projectname                  | gh-pages          |
| Project Page Owned By an Oganization | orgname.github.io/projectname                   | gh-pages          |
```