# github pages site can't find content

Tags: git, rest, github, github-pages

Like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747568/github-pages-site-cannot-find-files-404-errors) Github can't seem to find my scripts and content when published.

[image]

I've tried the suggestion solution and placed everything under the `gh-pages` branch but it doesn't seem to do the trick. I've also tried updating the settings to have them in the `master` branch with no luck there either.

Anyone have any other suggestions/insights? As you can see from the [repo](https://github.com/PrestonII/Git-It/tree/gh-pages) everything should be in the right place

EDIT:
The settings for the repo are currently pointing towards the gh-pages branch per the screenshot below:

[image: git-it-settings]

Comment: Have you gone into the settings tab and explicitly enabled github pages? https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#enabling-github-pages-to-publish-your-site-from-master-or-gh-pages

Comment: yeah @BrianaSwift - first thing I did unfortunately. Think there's any other settings I should've looked out for?

Comment: Not sure, I forked and am having the same issue. I would consider opening a ticket to GitHub support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Briana's suggestion I reached out to Github support and they clarified what the issue was.

- Seems that paths on Github Pages are case sensitive so the folder I had called `Content` was being called as `content` and couldn't be found.

**Basically, I changed `Content` to `content`**

- Paths with an underscore will not be stored, nor called by Github Pages per their [standards here](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/) Hadn't realized that either.

**Basically, I changed `_lib` to `lib`**

Comment: thank you @VonC - it was you and Briana who pushed me in the right direction! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I just tried http://prestonii.github.io/Git-It/, and don't get the same error.

I see a lot of `Unknown property ‘-moz-osx-font-smoothing’.  Declaration dropped.` in [`hover-min.css:12`](http://prestonii.github.io/Git-It/css/hover-min.css).

Check if your paths are case sensitive (you have your scripts under `Content`, not `content`)

Note: [`prestonii.github.io/Git-It/content/animate.css`](http://prestonii.github.io/Git-It/content/animate.css) refers to an html page with style embedded in it, representing a 404 page. It is not an actual stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in case anyone else runs into the same issue. I had this problem when I started the paths of referenced files with a "/" in my case the capitalization of letters, and underscores did not matter. I just simply removed the "/" and everything worked just fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33074258)

Answer (score 0):

For me helped to add

```json
"homepage": "https://Username.github.io/project-name"
```

to the `package.json`